# Flutter error : E/BufferQueueProducer( 3491): [SurfaceTexture-0-3491-33]:1338: disconnect: not connected (req=1)

Tags: flutter, error-handling

I'am new with flutter
When I change my view using a

```
Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => RoadMapPage(showAppbar: true)),
                )
```

My view is display but the error is present so for me its very strange.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.